# IntelliJ restarts server when updating resources

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, websphere

I ran into this problem at work, where we have a Spring boot Application and deploy the war exploded via a WebSphere.
When I change some static files like the html or JS and try to hotswap the changes via the update resource option, IntelliJ stops the application and deploys it again.
Now I was able to reproduce this problem at home but I still have no idea why this is happening.

I set up a new project with maven and added this example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-static

I downloaded the latest WebSphere and added the maven-war-plugin into my pom and finally deployed the whole thing.
When I change one line of code in the html and try to update the resources which usually should not be a problem the server stops and redeploys the application.

I am using the latest IntelliJ version 2017.2.3 and Maven 3.5.

Does anybody else have this issue or is it something I am missing in my set up?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html. You can change what happens on Update.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have the checkbox marked where it lets me choose what IntelliJ should do and I choose to only update the resources.

Comment: So this seems to be a problem on the side of IntelliJ with the version 2017.2 and up. I contacted them and once they come back to me I will close this question and answer it with some specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got a response. The whole thing is a bug and will be fixed some time next week. Here is the issue they opened up: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178845